# Dafny precondition checks in generated code

Tags: dafny, preconditions

I was wondering if there is a way to add precondition checks in the Dafny generated code. For example, let's take the following code snippet:

```
method MultipleReturns(x: int, y: int) returns (more: int, less: int)
   requires 0 < y
   ensures less < x < more
{
   more := x + y;
   less := x - y;
}
```

I'd like that the resulting code in C++ to have the following check:

```
assert(0 < y);
```

If this is not available in Dafny, what options do I have? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to turn the `requires` clause into a run-time check. The condition of a `requires` clause is in a ghost context, so it may not be compilable in general. Also, if you verify your program, then you know the condition is always going to evaluate to `true`, so there's no point in also checking it at run time.

To support situations where the condition to be checked is too difficult to verify statically, and especially to support cross-language situations where the caller is not written in Dafny and therefore not verified, Dafny has `expect` statements. You can use `expect` in your example to trade the statically verified precondition for a run-time check:

```
method MultipleReturns(x: int, y: int) returns (more: int, less: int)
   ensures less < x < more
{
   RuntimeRequires(0 < y);
   more := x + y;
   less := x - y;
}

method RuntimeRequires(cond: bool)
   ensures cond
{
   expect cond, "precondition failure";
}
```

Note that without the `requires` clause, you will not get any static verification at call sites.

As one other variation, you could use both a `requires` clause and the `RuntimeRequires` method I showed. If you do, I would suggest you change the specification of `RuntimeRequires` from an `ensures` to a `requires`, to make sure you have copied the condition correctly.

```
method MultipleReturns(x: int, y: int) returns (more: int, less: int)
   requires 0 < y
   ensures less < x < more
{
   RuntimeRequires(0 < y); // try changing this to 10 < y and see what happens
   more := x + y;
   less := x - y;
}

method RuntimeRequires(cond: bool)
   requires cond
{
  expect cond, "precondition failure";
}
```